# Cargar eventos en Fullcalendar con JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, fullcalendar, eventos

En javascript ya tengo la cadena JSON con los eventos para un fullcalendar. 
Es decir:

```
var eventos = $('#evaluaciones').val();
```

En la variable "eventos" ya tengo la cadena formateada con los eventos para el fullcalendar. 
De la forma (ejemplo):

> [{"title":"Integrador","start":"2018-12-03","end":"2018-12-03"},{"title":"Primer
>   Parcial","start":"2018-10-08","end":"2018-10-08"}]

Cómo debo hacer para que los muestre dentro de:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                lang: 'es',
                header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                editable: false,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                selectable: false,
                events: ????
});
```

No le encuentro la manera para poder cargarlos en el calendario y que los muestre. Me está faltando cómo llamarlo dentro de "events:".
Muchas gracias por la orientación!!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes directamente cargar dentro de events el resultado de la variable, con esto te debería de funcionar, siempre y cuando $('#evaluaciones').val() devuelva realmente el array con los JSON:

```
var eventos = $('#evaluaciones').val();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                lang: 'es',
                header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                editable: false,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                selectable: false,
                events: eventos
});
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Eso ya lo había intentado y nada.. no cargaba los eventos...
Después de buscarle mucho la vuelta, encontré la solución.. 
Lo que le estaba pasando a la variable "eventos" era una cadena con el formato  JSON. 
Pero me estaba faltando este paso: JSON.parse(eventos);
Con eso salió andando!!